# How to prevent resetting when rotating screen during user input

Tags: android, instance, android-alertdialog

My main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mAddProfileButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAddProfileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idAddNewProfileButton);
        mAddProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                alert.setTitle("Add New Profile");
                alert.setMessage("Name:");

                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // user pressed OK
                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // do something with the value!
                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                    }
                });

                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

So basically on the main screen you can press a button to add a new profile to my app. The user input dialog shows up fine when the user clicks the button, and they can enter in a name, but if you rotate the screen, it refreshes the activity and removes the prompt altogether.

Is there a way to preserve this? I'm familiar with the basic idea behind `OnSaveInstanceState` and `OnRestoreInstanceState` but I don't know how to get it to remember and re-instantiate the input dialog and what the user had entered thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you rotate the screen, it refreshes the activity and removes the prompt altogether.

It is unclear what "the prompt" is.

If by "the prompt", you mean your `AlertDialog`, that is because you are not using a `DialogFragment`. Wrap your `AlertDialog` in a `DialogFragment`, and the `DialogFragment` will handle the configuration change for you.

In [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Dialogs/DialogFragment), I have a `DialogFragment` create my `AlertDialog`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.dlgfrag;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SampleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
  private View form=null;

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    form=
        getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                     .inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    return(builder.setTitle(R.string.dlg_title).setView(form)
                  .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, this)
                  .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).create());
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    String template=getActivity().getString(R.string.toast);
    EditText name=(EditText)form.findViewById(R.id.title);
    EditText value=(EditText)form.findViewById(R.id.value);
    String msg=
        String.format(template, name.getText().toString(),
                      value.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface unused) {
    super.onDismiss(unused);

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Goodbye!");
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancel(DialogInterface unused) {
    super.onCancel(unused);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.back, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

The activity then just shows the `DialogFragment`, in this case triggered by a `Button` widget tied to the `showMe()` method in the layout:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.dlgfrag;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void showMe(View v) {
    new SampleDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "sample");
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get to pass back a value, though, as opposed to just outputting something with a toast. I'm also unsure how to use this code in general. I am new to Android development so this answer as it currently stands is a little over my head.

Comment: For example it cannot find `R.layout.dialog` or `R.string.dlg_title` or `R.string.toast` or `R.id.value` or `R.string.back`

Comment: And by the "prompt" I refer to everything taking place in the onclicklistener's onClick method for `mAddProfileButton`, which displays an OK and Cancel button and provides a field for user input to type things from the keyboard. If you type some stuff and rotate the screen, the entire prompt vanishes and you have to click the button again to re-enter something. I guess this is the same as the `AlertDialog` though.

Comment: Also `If by "the prompt", you mean your AlertDialog, that is because you are not using a DialogFragment.` Why is this the case? Why does using a DialogFragment vs. an AlertDialog have any difference with respect to the activity being destroyed/recreating on rotate?

Comment: @user6101402: "For example it cannot find" -- they are part of the overall project, located [where I linked to in my answer](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Dialogs/DialogFragment). "Why does using a DialogFragment vs. an AlertDialog have any difference with respect to the activity being destroyed/recreating on rotate?" -- `AlertDialog` knows nothing about the activity lifecycle. Fragments do. A `DialogFragment` exists largely to manage the creation, and re-creation, of the dialog for configuration changes and related scenarios.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to return the name/value to the place where it was called? (MainActivity) Because right now it appears that both are actually created in the onClick method which is a void, in the fragment class

Comment: @user6101402: Assuming an implementation akin to what I have above, call `getActivity()` in `onClick()`, to retrieve the `Activity` that is hosting the `DialogFragment`. Cast that to be the specific `Activity` subclass, or cast it to an interface (if more than one activity might show this `DialogFragment`). Then, call a method on your `Activity` subclass or interface, supplying whatever data you collected in the dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm just trying to pass back the String/int corresponding to name/value to MainActivity. Do I have to make them private member variables of the fragment class and open them up with getters and setters? I don't see how using getActivity() opens up access to those two variables to the place it was called.

Comment: @user6101402: "Do I have to make them private member variables of the fragment class and open them up with getters and setters?" -- no. "I don't see how using getActivity() opens up access to those two variables to the place it was called" -- if by "the place it was called", you mean a method somewhere in the activity, that's not possible. Displaying activities and dialogs is an asynchronous operation, not a blocking one. This is not unique to `DialogFragment` -- your original code was asynchronous as well, in that `show()` returns immediately.

Comment: So if I want to actually use this to tell my program how to make a new profile (by actually giving my program a name to work with), I'm not sure how I'd actually use this code to solve my problem as stated in the OP. I need to do more than just display a toast. I ultimately need access to the string.

Comment: @user6101402: Somewhere, triggered by `onClick()`, you "make a new profile". I do not know what is involved in "make a new profile". My guess is that it would not be the responsibility of a `DialogFragment`, but it might be the responsibility of the `Activity` that showed the `DialogFragment`. If that is indeed the case, write a `makeNewProfile()` method on your `MainActivity`. Call that method from `onClick()`, as I outlined in an earlier comment (e.g., `((MainActivity)getActivity()).makeNewProfile()`), passing in whatever data you got from the dialog that `makeNewProfile()` needs.

Comment: Maybe it'll be easier if I am more explicit: Say there is a method in MainActivity called `public String makeNewProfile(String profileName)` -- how/when would I invoke this? edit: We just crossposted, I'll read what you just said

Comment: That worked. Why does it need to be `((MainActivity)getActivity()).makeNewProfile())` and not something like `MainActivity.makeNewProfile()`, or `getActivity().makeNewProfile()`? I see `getActivity()` being used by itself elsewhere in this class. And `makeNewProfile` is localized to `MainActivity`

Comment: @user6101402: "Why... not something like MainActivity.makeNewProfile()" -- that would be invoking a `static` method. While possible, such a method would not have access to anything else inside your `MainActivity` instance. "or getActivity().makeNewProfile()?" -- because you did not write `Activity`. Google did. It does not have a `makeNewProfile()` method. Java is a "strongly typed" programming language. However, it supports casts, allowing you to call methods on the specific subclass.

Comment: What if you want to pass in custom text from MainActivity instead of using `R.string.dlg_title`? Or call an arbitrary function instead of `makeNewProfile()`? i.e. make the code more modular? Or is it accepted practice in this case to make a new Fragment class for each dialog you'd want to use throughout the app?

Comment: @user6101402: "What if you want to pass in custom text from MainActivity instead of using R.string.dlg_title?" -- use any number of Java techniques, such as a setter method. "Or call an arbitrary function instead of makeNewProfile()?" -- use any number of Java techniques, such as a callback or listener object. If you have further concerns about these topics, please use the "Ask Question" button to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.